# How to find the difference between two table in database without using join?

Tags: database

I need to find the difference between highest salary from a table called `myproject.faculty` and the highest salary from a table called `myproject.staff`. How can I do that?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myproject.faculty
```

Result:

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    CITY    STATE   ZIP     SALARY  DEPT    BIRTH_DATE  PHONE 
102     Jack    Sue     Frostburg   MD  21532   109000  COSC        3016783232 
1   Jo  Andorfer    Aberdeen    MD  21532   80000.89    COSC    01-FEB-81   301-687-5678
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myproject.staff
```

Result:

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    CITY    STATE   ZIP     SALARY  BIRTH_DATE  PHONE 
1   Xin     Zheng   Aberdeen    MD  21532   80000.89    01-FEB-81   301-687-5678 
2   Gerri   Wojnar  Aberdeen    FL  33423   78000.25    22-JAN-88   301-687-5679
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
select (select max(salary) from myproject.faculty) - (select max(salary) from myproject.staff)
```